# How to INSERT an id number into a blank table in a database with Coldfusion

Tags: mysql, sql, coldfusion

I'm trying to insert data into a blank table. The data comes from a form that is submitted. The table is set up with an auto-increment PK. The problem is that when I insert the info, the table does not get anything put into it. The info from the form includes everything but the PK number. When I then add the number manually then it works as normal. This is what the code looks like:

```
<cfquery name="updateInsOpTable" datasource="applewood">
INSERT INTO ins_opt_table
VALUES ('123 applewood road','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22')
</cfquery>
```

This throws an error because there is no PK. So how do I insert data into a table without a PK?

Comment: Are you sure your primary key is set up to auto-increment?  Something like this? `[MyId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL` If it is, it should just get the next value in the sequence.  Also, you might want to call out which columns you are inserting into.  E.g. `insert into ins_opt_table (column1, coumn2...)`.

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: Sorry about the bad tag. You were right Dean. All I had to do was put in the column names with the values and the PK auto-incremented. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @Dean, the last sentence of your comment is probably the correct answer.  Please post it as such.

Comment: Side note, be sure to use cfqueryparam on all user supplied values. Among other things, it help protect against sql injection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call out which columns you are inserting into. E.g. insert into ins_opt_table `(column1, coumn2...)`.